# Acessing Physical Memory In Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu-11.10

From my research so far, Linux is moving away from allowing access to physical memory via the /dev/mem file. Unfortunately this is the case on Ubuntu 11.10, as /dev/mem does not exist.

Further research turned up the shm file as a way to pass memory between programs (http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/what-is-devshm-and-its-practical-usage.html). This is to try to learn if /dev/shm is a valid substitute for hexdumping the contents of physical memory, e.g.,

```
dd if=/dev/shm bs=1024 count=10485576|hexdump -C > recovery.txt
```

Failing this, is there an alternate route to access physical memory in Linux when there is no /dev/mem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `/dev/shm` this way, it's a [temporary filesystem](https://superuser.com/questions/45342/when-should-i-use-dev-shm-and-when-should-i-use-tmp/45509#45509) that only provides a way to access information specifically stored in it.

You are right that you can't easily use `/dev/mem` this way. What's your use case? There's a probably a way to do what you want to do.

Comment: Dear David, thanks for answering. This isn't meant to be a part of a generalized process with an end user and Linux. There was some significant data in the gedit undo buffer pinched off by a mistaken keystroke, and the hope was the relevant RAM was not overwritten by any subsequent actions and could be recovered via this avenue.

Comment: In that case, dump the virtual memory of the gedit process (`/proc/<pid>/mem`) If it's anywhere, it'll be there.